# Layering transparent images and text on top of each other?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm still pretty new to Visual Studio. I have a few transparent images that I want to later on top of each other so that they appear as one image when put together. On top of that, I'm using DrawString to draw text on top of the images. I've been using DrawImage to display the images into a PictureBox, but I can't seem to get them to all display at once.

Edit: Here's some of the code I've been using.

```
private void drawTextBox()
    {
        var image = new Bitmap(this.pictureBox_TextBox.Width, this.pictureBox_TextBox.Height);
        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);

        graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Resources\TextBox.png"), new Point(0, 151));
        this.pictureBox_TextBox.Image = image;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using WinForms? Please share your implementation so far.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] so that we can help you.

Comment: Yup. I probably should have mentioned that earlier.

Comment: Do you have a separate call for each thing you want to draw? If so, you're _replacing_ it each time. You're supposed to use `Graphics` to build an image.